# Laravel: Error trying to remove image from storage

Tags: php, html, laravel

So When a user deletes a post on my website I want the image to be removed from storage. I have the code in place and the path should work but for some reason, it just returns the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found
```

Why is it looking inside the controller directory for storage directory? and why is it that it can find the image when it is displaying it.

Here is the block of code that is supposed to remove the image:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id){
    $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->firstOrFail();

    if($post->cover_image != 'noimage.jpg'){
        // Delete Image
        Storage::delete('/public/cover_images/'.$post->cover_image);
    }

    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'post deleted']);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't import `Storage` class. You can do it on the top of your controller:

```
use Storage;
```

Or just write in this way:

```
\Storage::delete('/public/cover_images/'.$post->cover_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

include `use Storage;` at the top of your controller.
You are using a facade without importing its namespace